# How to add a image over an image at a specific x and y coordinates

Tags: jquery, image, draggable, overlapping

I am building a draggable map for a game, (the map started as a school project, and i am transferring it into a game) the link of the map is [here](http://www.daparadise.com/test/island.php)

I would like to add a second image over this image at a specific location no matter where the map is dragged in it's container.

Here is the jquery:

```
$(function() { 
    $("#map").draggable({
        cursor: 'move',
        containment: [-525, -582, 252, 40]
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="mapable" style="position: relative;float:left;height:423px;width:1072px;overflow:hidden;border:1px solid black;">
    <img src="include/map.png" style="display:block;border:1px solid black;position: absolute;" onclick="point_it(event);" class="drag-image" id="map"/>
</div>
```

For full source of all the code you can view it [here](http://www.daparadise.com/test/source.php)